# Why this behavior when coercing a list to character via as.character()?

Tags: list, r, coercion

In the process of (mostly) answering [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7591295/324364) question, I stumbled across something that I feel like I really should already have seen before. Let's say you've got a list:

```
l <- list(a = 1:3, b = letters[1:3], c = runif(3))
```

Attempting to coerce `l` to various types returns an error:

```
> as.numeric(l)
Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
> as.logical(l)
Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'logical'
```

However, I'm apparently allowed to coerce a list to character, I just wasn't expecting this result:

```
> as.character(l)
[1] "1:3"                                                        
[2] "c(\"a\", \"b\", \"c\")"                                     
[3] "c(0.874045701464638, 0.0843329173512757, 0.809434881201014)"
```

Rather, if I'm allowed to coerce lists to character, I would have thought I'd see behavior more like this:

```
> as.character(unlist(l))
[1] "1"                  "2"                  "3"                  "a"                  "b"                 
[6] "c"                  "0.874045701464638"  "0.0843329173512757" "0.809434881201014"
```

Note that *how I specify the list elements originally* affects the output of `as.character`:

```
l <- list(a = c(1,2,3), b = letters[1:3], c = runif(3))
> as.character(l)
[1] "c(1, 2, 3)"                                                 
[2] "c(\"a\", \"b\", \"c\")"                                     
[3] "c(0.344991483259946, 0.0492411875165999, 0.625746068544686)"
```

I have two questions:

1. How is `as.character` dredging up the information from my original creation of the list `l` in order to spit out `1:3` versus `c(1,2,3)`.
2. In what circumstances would I want to do this, exactly? When would I want to call `as.character()` on a list and get output of this form?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For non-trivial lists, `as.character` uses `deparse` to generate the strings.

1. Only if the vector is integer and 1,2,3,...,n - then it deparses as `1:n`.

   `c(1,2,3)` is double whereas `1:3` is integer...
2. No idea :-)

...but look at `deparse` if you want to understand `as.character` here:

```
deparse(c(1L, 2L, 3L)) # 1:3
deparse(c(3L, 2L, 1L)) # c(3L, 2L, 1L)
deparse(c(1, 2, 3))    # c(1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: Aha, `deparse` does seem to explain much of my first question.

Answer (score 6):

The help file does say

> For lists it deparses the elements individually, except that it extracts the first element of length-one character vectors.

I'd seen this before in trying to answer a question [not online] about `grep`.  Consider:

```
> x <- list(letters[1:10],letters[10:19])
> grep("c",x)
[1] 1 2
```

`grep` uses `as.character` on `x`, with the result that, since both have `c(` in them, both components match.  That took a while to figure out.

On "**Why does it do this?**", I'd guess that one of the members of R core wanted it to do this.

Comment: This is one reason why R, great as it is for statistical programming, will never catch on outside the narrow community of those who work with it exclusively or are willing to devote an inordinate amount of energy to dealing with its unpredictable behavior.