# As.character returning numbers instead of strings R

Tags: r, data.table

This is what I am referring to:

```
    > dt[1]
       RMove YMove BMove Red Yellow Blue Rm Ym Bm Rchar Ychar Bchar
    1:   1_b   1_a   1_b   0      0    0  1  1  1     b     a     b
    > as.character(dt[1])
     [1] "1"  "1"  "1"  "18" "6"  "9"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "2"  "1"  "1"
```

Looking at the structure:

```
    > str(dt[1])
    Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  1 obs. of  12 variables:
    $ RMove : Factor w/ 9 levels "1_b","2_a","2_c",..: 1
    $ YMove : Factor w/ 6 levels "1_a","1_b","2_b",..: 1
    $ BMove : Factor w/ 6 levels "1_b","2_c","3_b",..: 1
    $ Red   : Factor w/ 23 levels "-0.5","-1.5",..: 18
    $ Yellow: Factor w/ 21 levels "-0.5","-1.5",..: 6
    $ Blue  : Factor w/ 18 levels "-1","-1.5","-12",..: 9
    $ Rm    : Factor w/ 4 levels "1","2","3","4": 1
    $ Ym    : Factor w/ 4 levels "1","2","3","4": 1
    $ Bm    : Factor w/ 4 levels "1","2","3","4": 1
    $ Rchar : Factor w/ 3 levels "a","b","c": 2
    $ Ychar : Factor w/ 2 levels "a","b": 1
    $ Bchar : Factor w/ 2 levels "b","c": 1
    - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

So I get that I've turned this into factors. But I'm unclear on what the numbers at the end of each of these lines represent (Like the 1 at the end of the RMove line)  and given that these are in a list how do I get it to display the characters ("1_a")?

And if you would like to see all the code I used to get to this point. The factors come in at the bottom when I want to use split on the table:

```
PieceValue = data.frame("a" = 3, "b" = 5, "c" = 7)
ColorCode = data.frame("R" = 1, "Y" = 2, "B" = 3)

#Setting the starting Conditions
L1 = c( "Ra","Rc","Bc")
Z1 = 2
L2 = c("Rb","Bb","Ya")
Z2 = 2
L3 = c("Yb")
Z3 = 0
L4 = c()
Z4 = 0

#Sample Strategies
# SR = "3-c"
# SB = "2-c"
# SY = "2-b"

#Strategy set for each player
ROne = c("1_b")
RTwo = c("2_a","2_c")
RThree = c("3_a","3_b","3_c")
RFour = c("4_a", "4_b", "4_c")
StrSetRed = list(ROne,RTwo,RThree, RFour)

YOne = c("1_a","1_b")
YTwo = c("2_b")
YThree = c("3_a")
YFour = c("4_a","4_b")
StrSetYellow = list(YOne,YTwo,YThree, YFour)

BOne = c("1_b")
BTwo = c("2_c")
BThree = c("3_b","3_c")
BFour = c("4_b","4_c")
StrSetBlue = list(BOne,BTwo, BThree, BFour)

#Checks the safety of the room
Safety = function(Li, Zi){
  if(length(Li)>Zi){
    return(TRUE)
  } else{
    return(FALSE)
  }
}

#Calcuates the payout of that room
#Bug with Payout
Payout = function(Li,Zi){
  temp = c(0,0,0)
  Payo = c(0,0,0)
  if (Safety(Li,Zi) == FALSE){
    for(i in Li){
      z = strsplit(i,"")[[1]]
      point = PieceValue[[z[2]]]
      player = ColorCode[[z[1]]]
      temp[player] = -point
      temp[-player] = (point)/2
      #Bug check
#       print(point)
#       print(player)
#       print(temp)
#       print (i)
      Payo = Payo + temp
#       print(Payo)
    }
  }
  return(Payo)
}

#Calculates the payout of the Strategies
#Bug with adding non existing characters
#Make sure all moves are possible otherwise bug
#Fixed(?) other bugs, still have to make the bounce happen
EvalPay = function(SR,SY,SB){
  colors = c("R", "Y", "B")
  Strat = c(SR,SY, SB)
  Room = list(L1,L2,L3,L4)
  Capacity = c(4,4,3,99)
  Zombies = c(Z1,Z2,Z3,Z4)
  Payoffs = c(0,0,0)
  for(i in 1:4){
    location = Room[[i]]
    zeds = Zombies[i]
    #print("BigLoop")
    for(j in 1:3){
      #print("Small Loop")
     s = Strat[j]
     si = strsplit(s,"_")[[1]]
     c = colors[j]
     location = grep(paste(c, si[2], sep = ""), location, 
              value = TRUE, invert = TRUE)
     if(i == si[1]){
       #If the room is full they bound to the parking lot
       if(Capacity[i]<=length(location) || i == 4){
         Room[[4]] = c(Room[[4]], paste(c,si[2], sep =""))
#          print("Full")
#          print(Room[[4]])
       } else{
       location = c(location, paste(c,si[2], sep = ""))
     } 
    } 
    }
    #To fix bug with the function making room 4 empty 
    if(i != 4){
     Room[[i]] = location
     Payoffs = Payoffs + (Payout(location,zeds))
    } else {
#       print(Payoffs)
#       print(Payout(Room[[4]], zeds))
    Payoffs = Payoffs + (Payout(Room[[4]], zeds))
    }


  }
  #Bug Check
  #print(Room)
  #print("EndLoop")
return(Payoffs)
}


#Makes A table of possible strategies given Room Number
#Check bugs
MakeStratTable = function(StrRed,StrYell,StrBlue){
  StratTable = matrix(c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA), ncol = 6)
  for(a in StrRed){
    for(b in StrYell){
      for(c in StrBlue){
        pay = EvalPay(a,b,c)
        temp = matrix(c(a,b,c,pay), ncol = 6)
        StratTable = matrix(rbind(StratTable,temp), ncol = 6)
      }
    }
  }
  StratTable = StratTable[-1,]
#   colnames(StratTable) = c("Rmove","YMove","BMove","Red","Yellow",
#                            "Blue")
  return(StratTable)
}

#Making the Grand Table
FullTable = function(){
times = 1
for(t in StrSetRed){
  for(u in StrSetYellow){
    for(v in StrSetBlue){
      temp = MakeStratTable(t,u,v)
      if(times != 1){
        FullTable = matrix(rbind(FullTable,temp), ncol = 6)
      } else {
        FullTable = temp
      }
      times = times + 1

    }
  }
}
colnames(FullTable) = c("RMove","YMove","BMove","Red","Yellow",
                         "Blue")
return(FullTable)
}

library(data.table)
BestResponse = function(frame, score){
  temp = frame[with(frame,order(-(as.integer(score))))]
  temp = temp[1,]
  return(temp)
}

#Part 2
Total = FullTable()
dt = data.table(Total)
#In order to set up sortable factors
dt$Rm = as.integer(unlist(lapply(strsplit(as.character(dt$RMove), "_"), "[",1)))
dt$Ym = as.integer(unlist(lapply(strsplit(as.character(dt$YMove), "_"), "[",1)))
dt$Bm = as.integer(unlist(lapply(strsplit(as.character(dt$BMove), "_"), "[",1)))
dt$Rm = as.factor(dt$Rm)
dt$Ym = as.factor(dt$Ym)
dt$Bm = as.factor(dt$Bm)
dt$Rchar = as.factor(unlist(lapply(strsplit(as.character(dt$RMove), "_"), "[",2)))
dt$Ychar = as.factor(unlist(lapply(strsplit(as.character(dt$YMove), "_"), "[",2)))
dt$Bchar = as.factor(unlist(lapply(strsplit(as.character(dt$BMove), "_"), "[",2)))
dt2 = split(dt,list(dt$Rm,dt$Ym,dt$Bm,dt$Rchar,dt$Ychar))
```

Comment: I think your actual problem is that you are confused about the difference between `[` and `[[`. Try it again using `[[`.

Comment: Hmm, I think I see what you mean. as.character(dt[[1]]) or as.character(dt$RMove) does return it as what I want. I'm still a little bit mystified by factors and the numbers at the end though.

Comment: Well, the confusion here is compounded by the fact that `dt[1]` behaves differently for a data.table than for a data.frame. In your case, with a data.table you get the first _row_, which R is attempting to convert to character. I assume you're getting the integer codes as characters.

Comment: Just another reminder of how very much more I have to learn about R, Thank you!

Comment: This huge code you've posted, is it necessary at all to explain this problem you've mentioned in the title?

Comment: I don't think so, it was just in case what I was doing wrong had happened earlier in my code, but instead in seemed like it was just me not understanding the first part posted above

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7591632/why-this-behavior-when-coercing-a-list-to-character-via-as-character) question involves a similar question when using `as.character` on a list object.

The solution is easy enough.

```
> as.character(unlist(dt[1]))
 [1] "1_b" "1_a" "1_b" "0"   "0"   "0"   "1"   "1"   "1"   "b"   "a"   "b"
```