# Why are dates in a list first converted to numeric when coercing to character

Tags: r, string, date

I'm trying to convert a column of dates into strings, because I want to use them as factor levels at some later point in my code.

The date column is part of a tibble, and is of class Date. I figured that a simple as.character() conversion would do the trick, but unfortunately I was wrong. Instead of neatly formatted strings it returns a number in string form. For example today (22 november 2017) would come out as "17492". So somewhere in the process the date gets converted into its numeric format and only then turned into a character string.

Now I did find a workaround, by unlisting the data, converting it again to dates and then to character strings, but it is fairly inefficient.

Can anyone explain i) why this occurs and ii) if there is an easier fix?

Below a reproducible example:

```
#Get current system date
foo <-Sys.Date()
#Convert to list
foo <- as.list(foo)
#The following then produces the number string:
as.character(foo)
[1] "17492"
#The following code works but is a rather annoying work-around
as.character(as.Date(unlist(foo), origin=as.Date("1970-01-01")))
[1] "2017-11-22"
```

Comment: `lapply(foo, as.character)`

Comment: Is there a reason you are storing your dates in a list rather than a simple vector in your example? Normally columns in tibbles are stored as vectors. Does your reproducible example accurately reflect your real problem?

Comment: @d.b Great, thanks. Works like a breeze.

Comment: As for the "why", it's a general thing with using `as.character` on lists, not having to do with dates in particular. There's a very good duplicate I'm trying to find...

Comment: If your dates are in column `date` of the tibble `mydata` you can also use `dplyr::mutate`. For example `mydata %>% mutate(datechar = as.character(date))`.

Comment: Based on `?as.character`, it seems like running `as.character` on lists effectively does something like `unlist(lapply(foo, function(x) as.character(deparse(as.vector(x)))))` but I'll let someone more knowledgeable tackle the **why**

Comment: @MrFlick Aren't tibbles supposed to be lists? I first noted the problem for the tibble but then observed the same behavior for data.frames and lists and thought I'd ask the question in a broader sense.

Comment: @d.b Exactly, the "why" is mostly just because since lists could potentially hold anything as elements, `as.character` doesn't really make much sense in that context.

Comment: @MaartenPunt Mr Flick means why are you storing the dates in a _list column_ rather than date column, specifically. List columns can be awkward.

Comment: Finally found the question I was [thinking](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7591632/324364) of.

Comment: @MaartenPunt tibbles and data.frames are basically lists, but typically lists of atomic vectors. So a list of vectors, rather than a list of lists. Often you wind up with lists with sloppy data manipulation rather than intentionally trying to have a list. With `tt<-tibble(date=c(Sys.Date(), Sys.Date()))`, you have a list with one column and that one column is an atomic Date vector `class(tt$date)`, not a list. And here `as.character(tt$date)` works just fine.

Comment: @joran I see. The structure of the data is basically inherited from how it was produced. I matched a number of strings with their first occurence in an ordered dataset and then used that to extract the dates from a date column. In any case the example did replicate the problem, and d.b. solution solved it. I'll check out the other question

Comment: Seems like the basic issue is that running `as.character(foo)` where foo is a 1-column tibble is not the same as `as.character(foo$date)`.

Comment: @MrFlick Oh now I see where I went wrong. I did miss the dollar sign. Most probably because the tibble in this case is a single column. I apologize for my stupidity. But at least I learned a lot of new stuff as to why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the amount of useful comments and the final solutions provided I'll post an answer summary here.

The first thing to do if you run into this problem is check whether you actually want to convert the full list, or **a column within the list, with the column actually being a vector**. This was my underlying problem as MrFlick and neilfws pointed out. The reason I missed that was because in my case the list was a one column tibble, the column being named "date". Using `as.character(foo)` returned my "numeric string" `"17492"`, but using `as.character(foo$date)`, did exactly what it was supposed to do and returned `"2017-11-22"`.

In case your list is really just a list, or a list of lists, the solution of d.b. works like a breeze: use `lapply(foo, as.character)` or `sapply(foo, as.character)` depending a bit on your desired output.

Now as to the why this happens: the direct reason, as pointed out by d.b. is that if `as.character()` encounters a list it first `unlist()` it, and then does the conversion.

The deeper why was pointed out by joran and the duplicate question on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7591632/324364). In short: usually it does not make sense to convert a full list to a single data type class, as it can can contain many. For example `as.numeric(foo)` would just return an error. The only exception to that is  `as.character()`, that actually makes a full write-out of the list (perhaps to keep records).